# Why am I not able to change the global commit author?

Tags: git, github

I am using the following commands to change my user details:

```
git config --global user.name myusername
git config --global user.email myemail
```

I pulled a public remote repository from account linked with myusername and when I was trying to push changes it gave the following error:

```
remote: Permission to myusername/project.git denied to oldusername.
```

Although I changed it, it still tries to push through the old username only. Why? What am I missing here?
After checking the `git config user.name`, I found out that it shows myusername only and not the oldusername!

Comment: The user name and email address is used when committing, it isn't used when authenticating with a remote during a push, that's done either using a separate username and password, or a ssh key, depending on the remote url. Most likely you have an old ssh key that you're using that isn't added to the remote repository and given push access. What you stamp into each commit is rather irrelevant to this process.

Answer (score 3):

See [Jordan Lewis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43458756/1256452) for why the push itself fails.

Note, however, that your configured `user.name` and `user.email` are used on commits you make, from the time you configure them.

Hence if you already made three commits with an *old* `user.name` and/or `user.email`, then change them and make one *new* commit, you now have *four* commits, three with the old name and one with the new.

When you run `git push` you tell your Git to offer, to their (other) Git, all commits you have that they don't have.  That would be all four of these commits.  (And if that newest commit you made has, as its parent, one of the three "wrong name" commits you made, your Git *must* send both the wrong-name and right-name commits for your latest right-name commit to get added.)

[See also this answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1320317/1256452), for help in copying the commits you made with the "wrong" name/email to new ones with corrected name/email.

Answer (score 3):

The problem might be that you're pushing with a key that's attached to your `oldusername` account, but that key isn't added to your `myusername` account.

There's a [help document](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-to-user-repo-denied-to-other-user/) that describes exactly this issue.